# How to maintain formulas with get_all_records() in pygsheets?

Tags: python, pygsheets

I'm using pygsheets to update and manipulate a Google sheet. I use `get_all_records` to import the data into a list of dictionaries like so -

```py
gsheetRecords = ws.get_all_records(empty_value = '', head = 1)  # returns a list of dictionaries
```

But this call doesn't preserve any formulas and hardcodes the resultant values that display in the cells.  So if cell A2 is 22 and cell B2 is `=A2*3`, `get_all_records` pulls in the value of 66 for cell B2.

I checked the documentation and a couple of online primers but couldn't figure it out. Any advice or work arounds would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value_render=ValueRenderOption.FORMULA` and it should return the direct formula than formatted values. since the kwargs of get_all_records are passed to get_values. you can see the [param here in docs](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_values).

```
gsheetRecords = ws.get_all_records(empty_value = '', head = 1, value_render=ValueRenderOption.FORMULA)
```

Comment: super - thank you!